# POD - proper orthogonal decomposition for Reduced Order Modelling

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how to perform a Proper Orthogonal composition, of which an example of the procedure and analysis are found in the following tutorial video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5GhhjpX0ao

It is basically solving a PDE using spectral methods with the FFT and then taking the SVD on the resulting simulation data.

I am stuck on basically using NDSolve in place of ode45() from Matlab.

I was thinking that maybe it is possible to produce an interpolating function for solving a given PDE, but then unsure how to extract the sequence of numerical data for each time step such that I could feed it into the SVD function.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check-in Mathematica documentation to know more on how to use NDsolve. It takes your differential equation and initial conditions as input.

Comment: Your question could be a bit more specific and show what you have coded up so far.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have an answer for you but a few pointers. First, there is an example of a model order reduction (MOR) in the finite element documentation. You can find that in the section [Model Order Reduction of Transient PDEs with Stationary Coefficients and Stationary Boundary Conditions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). That, however, is not based on POD. The second pointer is to a talk I gave a few moons back about programming the finite element method implemented in the language. You can find that in the presentation called [Writing Your Own PDE Solvers - The Finite Element Method Interface](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9312/). That contains a suggestion for writing a function `NDSingularValueDecomposition` that would work somewhat analog to `NDEigensystem` but produce the singular value decomposition of a discretized PDE.

If you want answers that are more specific to the code you work on you should share that code in your question. I do not think chances are high that someone will type all that stuff from the presentation...